# Receiving "invalid argument" when trying to upload file using webdriver.io

Tags: javascript, typescript, e2e-testing, webdriver-io

I have a Typescript project using webdriver.io , I am trying to upload a file to a file input but keep getting an error saying "invalid argument".

I am using:

- Webdriver.io v8.24.3
- Nodejs: 18.17.1
- Chrome browser capability
- Running on my local device ( Macbook pro M1 )

This is the html input that I am trying to upload the file on:

```html
<input 
  class="tw-block w-full text-sm text-gray-500 file:mr-4 file:py-2 file:px-4 file:rounded-full file:border-0 file:text-sm file:font-semibold file:bg-blue-50 file:text-blue-700 hover:file:bg-blue-100" 
  name="document" 
  type="file" 
  accept=".pdf"
/>
```

This is my code that handles uploading the file. I have tried these 2 variations:

```js
import path, { dirname } from "node:path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "node:url";
import { OnboardingFlowPageClass } from "../onboarding-flow.page.js";

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);

class NewHealthyHomesStepPageClass extends OnboardingFlowPageClass {
  public get fileUploadInput() {
    return $("input[name='document']");
  }

  public async uploadFile() {
    const docPath = path.resolve(
      __dirname,
      "../../../../../resources/documents/healthy-homes.pdf",
    );

    await this.fileUploadInput.waitForDisplayed();
    await this.fileUploadInput.waitForEnabled();

    await this.fileUploadInput.setValue(docPath);
  }
}
```

and

```js
class NewHealthyHomesStepPageClass extends OnboardingFlowPageClass {
  public get fileUploadInput() {
    return $("input[name='document']");
  }

  public async uploadFile() {
    const docPath = path.resolve(
      __dirname,
      "../../../../../resources/documents/healthy-homes.pdf",
    );

    await this.fileUploadInput.waitForDisplayed();
    await this.fileUploadInput.waitForEnabled();
    const remoteFilePath = await browser.uploadFile(docPath);

    await this.fileUploadInput.setValue(remoteFilePath);
  }
}
```

This is the error that I get when the uploadFile() function is called:

```
invalid argument: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=119.0.6045.199)
    at getErrorFromResponseBody (file:///Users/reizar/Code/test_suite/node_modules/webdriver/build/utils.js:195:12)
    at NodeJSRequest._request (file:///Users/reizar/Code/test_suite/node_modules/webdriver/build/request/index.js:193:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Element.wrapCommandFn (file:///Users/reizar/Code/test_suite/node_modules/@wdio/utils/build/shim.js:82:29)
    at async Element.wrapCommandFn (file:///Users/reizar/Code/test_suite/node_modules/@wdio/utils/build/shim.js:82:29)
    at async Element.elementErrorHandlerCallbackFn (file:///Users/reizar/Code/test_suite/node_modules/webdriverio/build/middlewares.js:18:32)
    at async Element.wrapCommandFn (file:///Users/reizar/Code/test_suite/node_modules/@wdio/utils/build/shim.js:82:29)
    at async Element.wrapCommandFn (file:///Users/reizar/Code/test_suite/node_modules/@wdio/utils/build/shim.js:82:29)
    at async Element.elementErrorHandlerCallbackFn (file:///Users/reizar/Code/test_suite/node_modules/webdriverio/build/middlewares.js:18:32)
    at async Element.wrapCommandFn (file:///Users/reizar/Code/test_suite/node_modules/@wdio/utils/build/shim.js:82:29)
```

This is what the docPath outputs (I have triple checked that this path is correct and there is a valid pdf at this file path):

```
/Users/reizar/Code/test_suite/resources/documents/healthy-homes.pdf
```

I have checked that this error is happening at the setValue() call and not the previous waitFor calls.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.